# In Ubuntu how can I find out the DNS servers used from the command line?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

I need to know the addresses and ports of the Ubuntu DNS servers. How can I do this from the command line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Command-line: `$ cat /etc/resolv.conf`

DNS servers listen by convention on port 53 TCP or UDP; UDP is used for most requests.

Answer (score 3):

Command-Line:

```
nm-tool | grep DNS
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean your local dns servers:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

and for information as to what port a general service runs on you can grep /etc/services for dns

If you mean the ubuntu DNS servers for the domain just use nslookup

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays the following would help more, due to nm-tool is often missed:

```
nmcli dev show | grep DNS
```